# Creating overlapping histograms in ggplot from unbalanced data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 in R to plot multiple overlapping histograms. I've seen on other answers like this:

```
ggplot(histogram, aes(f0)) + 
geom_histogram(data = lowf0, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) + 
geom_histogram(data = mediumf0, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
geom_histogram(data = highf0, fill = "green", alpha = 0.2)
```

This would work perfectly if my data were coming from vectors of equal length but they are not. I currently have this set up to create two separate plots using two different, single-vector dataframes for each. I've looked all over but have been unable to find anything with different size data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your data so you have a column that contains the level.  Then `ggplot` has a grouping option

```
times=c(10, 20, 30)
dat <- data.frame(levs=rep(c("low", "med", "high"), times=times),
                  counts=rexp(60, rate=c(rep(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), times=times))))
ggplot(dat, aes(counts, fill=levs, group=levs)) + 
    geom_histogram(position="dodge", alpha=0.2)
```

Overlapping density might look better though

```
ggplot(dat, aes(counts, fill=levs, group=levs)) + 
    geom_density(alpha=0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you explain just a bit more what you're doing with how you're constructing your data frame though?

Comment: Took me about a day of learning about long vs wide data structures to get what's going on here but this is perfect, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(f0)) + 
geom_histogram(data = histogram, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) + 
geom_histogram(data = lowf0, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) + 
geom_histogram(data = mediumf0, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
geom_histogram(data = highf0, fill = "green", alpha = 0.2)
```

If you don't specify the data initially, you should be able to include data having different lengths.